# Format phone number in Laravel Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is there a simple way to format a phone string for display in a [Laravel](https://laravel-ar.com/language/2/%D8%AA%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%85-laravel) Blade template?

I am trying to take '612345678'

and insert it as {{ $user{'phone'] }} and have it display as 612 345 678

Answer (score 8):

Feel free to use the following package:
https://github.com/Propaganistas/Laravel-Phone

and use it for example:

```
{{ phone('612345678'); }}
{{ phone($user['phone'], 'US'); }}
```

Answer (score 2):

add the function in the model

```
public function phoneNumber() {
    // add logic to correctly format number here
    // a more robust ways would be to use a regular expression
    return "(".substr($data, 0, 3).") ".substr($data, 3, 3)." ".substr($data,6);
}
```

and display it into your blade as

```
{{ $user->phoneNumber() }}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will give you (###) ###-####

```
preg_replace('~.*(\d{3})[^\d]{0,7}(\d{3})[^\d]{0,7}(\d{4}).*~', '($1) $2-$3', $simple->phone)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$format = chunk_split($user['phone'], 3, ' ');
```

You will get your phone number as "612 345 678 " with a space trailing behind.
To remove the last space trailing behind, you can use rtrim() function.

```
rtrim($format, ' ');
```

Hope this works.